# Organizing Code Into Git SubModules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I would like to know whether Git submodules are an appropriate
organization for some code that I currently keep under RCS, and if
so, how the submodules should be organized.

#### General outline of modules

Suppose I have a collection of library modules (maybe libraries, maybe
parts of single library; that's one item up for discussion).
Suppose some of those modules are base modules, and other modules depend
on the base modules.
All of these modules are intended to be used by yet other packaged
software (programs), which would presumably include an appropriate
selection of these packages as submodules.

To make it concrete, the library modules are:

- `stderr` — standardized error reporting routines (not dependent on
  other modules).
- `filter` — file filter programs (like `grep` or `cat`): uses
  `stderr`.
- `debug` — debug trace support: uses `stderr`
- `phasedtest` — unit code testing: uses `filter`, `debug` and
  `stderr` directly.
- `rational` - a rational number arithmetic package that uses
  `phasedtest` for its test code, but is independent of `phasedtest`
  and its dependencies otherwise.

Many other programs use `stderr`.
Quite a lot of those use also use `filter` (and all code that uses
`filter` also uses `stderr` directly), but there are quite a lot of
programs that do use `stderr` but don't use `filter`.
Some programs use `debug`; essentially all those programs also use
`stderr` directly, but they may or may not use `filter` directly.
Unit test programs using `phasedtest` may or may not use `stderr`,
`filter` and `debug` directly (they're more likely to use `stderr` than
the others), but `phasedtest` itself needs them so such programs always
use those modules indirectly.
Some programs may use `rational`; usually they will use `stderr` too
(nearly everything written by me uses `stderr`), but those programs don't
directly use `phasedtest` themselves, in general.

Just for clarification: at the moment, these potential Git modules and
submodules are not in Git at all; most of them have extensive (10-30
year) histories in RCS (SCCS prior to Y2K), which will be preserved when
they are transitioned to Git.
The intention is to get all the repos into GitHub in due course.
In general, these modules are all fairly stable.
They do get revised or extended, but not necessarily every year.
Sometimes, three or more years go by without changes to some of them.
I have a build/distribution system where the files that make up what
might become submodules are pulled into the distribution of the larger
program when that is being prepared for release.
During normal (single-person) development, the material lives in a
library with hundreds of source files built into a single (static)
library (in `$HOME/lib`), and a single header directory (`$HOME/inc`,
analogous to, but wholly separate from, either `/usr/include` or
`/usr/local/include`).

I'm seeking to get the structure "right" — sufficiently right that I
won't regret what I've done — before transitioning them to Git.
I still have version stamping and tagging issues to resolve; that's a
whole separate bag'o'worms and not part of this question.

#### How should submodules be organized?

From my understanding of submodules, it appears that:

- `stderr` should be in its own repository.
- `filter` should be in its own repository with `stderr` as a submodule.
- `debug` should be in its own repository with `stderr` as a submodule.
- `phasedtest` should be in its own repository with:

  - `debug` as one submodule
  - `filter` as one submodule
  - but should it also include `stderr` as a direct submodule, or
    should it use the version of `stderr` from the nested submodules
    (the `stderr` inside `debug` and/or the `stderr` from inside
    `filter`)?
- `rational` should be in its own repository with `phasedtest` as a
  submodule (and whatever sub-submodule organization comes with
  `phasedtest`).

#### Issues arising

1. Both `filter` and `debug` independently need the `stderr` submodule
   (but they're unlikely to be depend significantly on any particular
   version of `stderr` -- almost any working version at release level
   10 will suffice).  So, they both need a version of `stderr` in a submodule.
2. How many libraries: should there be?  Options include:

   - Should there be three separate libraries: `libstderr`, `libdebug`,
     and `libfilter`?
   - Or should `libfilter` include the material from `stderr`, and
     should `libdebug` include the material from `stderr` (two
     libraries)?
   - Or should there be a single composite library `libjlss` with
     elements of `stderr`, `debug` and `filter` in it?
   - Does the answer vary if the libraries are shared rather than
     static?
3. Should the `phasedtest` code be organized as a fourth library
   containing the modules `stderr`, `filter` and `debug` as submodules
   (so that `stderr` will appear three times, once as a direct
   dependency and twice as a dependency of `debug` and `filter`), or
   should it be a smaller library that requires linking with the three
   separate dependent libraries?
4. Since the `rational` module only requires `phasedtest` for testing,
   it won't install the `phasedtest` library or libraries.
   But it will need them available for testing.
   Should it require the pre-installed `phasedtest` library (libraries),
   or should it be self-contained and have the necessary code for
   testing as part of its distribution?
5. Programs using `rational` might also use `stderr` (probably would),
   but might or might not use `debug` and `filter`, and would be
   unlikely to use `phasedtest` except for unit testing their own
   components.

## Main questions

- Are Git submodules the right way to go, or should I be looking at an
  alternative organization?
- Assuming that Git submodules are appropriate, how would the Git
  repositories be best organized?

### Auxilliary questions

- Is there a minimum sensible size for a repository?
- Is there a maximum sensible number of submodules for a single repository?
- Does it matter if a single submodule is a sub-submodule of a number of
  of submodules used by a single repository?
- Is there a conventional directory structure for submodules?
  All directories directly in the top-level directory, or some in
  standard directory name in the root directory, or in quasi-random
  locations in the superproject directory hierarchy?
- Are there any glaring gotchas that I've not spotted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first two questions ("are git submodules appropriate?" and "how should I organize them?") aren't really a good fit for stackoverflow: the answers are going to mostly be matters of opinion, and it would be hard to identify any single answer as "correct".

Your auxiliary questions are slightly more addressable:

> Is there a minimum sensible size for a repository?

Not really, no.

> Is there a maximum sensible number of submodules for a single repository?

Again, no, but before creating a monster repository with hundreds of submodules make sure you are familiar working with them *first*.  People have different opinions on how best to manage submodules.  [Here is one person](https://www.philosophicalhacker.com/post/using-git-submodules-effectively/) who has spent some time thinking about. I don't agree with all his ideas, but it is at least a way to start thinking about the issue.

> Does it matter if a single submodule is a sub-submodule of a number of of submodules used by a single repository?

Not really, no, although if you have multiple instances of a repository scattered about your sources you are probably going to run into issues of version skew (e.g., one is at version A and another is at version B and another is at version C) unless you are very careful.

> Is there a conventional directory structure for submodules? All directories directly in the top-level directory, or some in standard directory name in the root directory, or in quasi-random locations in the superproject directory hierarchy?

There is not, but typically you will pick something that works for you and stick with it.  I have seen many projects that place submodules into a `lib` or `modules` directory, while others do place them at the top-level.

> Are there any glaring gotchas that I've not spotted?

Remember that when checked out as a submodule, the current HEAD is managed by the parent repository. That is, if you `cd` into a submodule, make changes, push them, and then in the parent project run `git submodule update`, you will roll back the local copy of your submodule to whatever commit is recorded in the parent.

It is for this reason that I generally treat submodules as read-only instances of a repository that only ever get updated by running `git pull` (followed by a subsequent commit in the parent repository).  I only edit files in the standalone checkout of the repository.

You need to train yourself to regularly run `git submodule update` after pulling new changes into the parent repository (in case those changes included new versions of your submodules).

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you have 3 options submodules, subtree or dependencies (static libraries that is pre-built). I've been using submodules a lot recently and that is a way to put git repos inside a git repo and track which commit of the submodules repo your root repo is using. If you need to make changes in the submodules you should use submodules, otherwise go for subtree, or dependencies.

To use dependencies, you need some kind of tool that can pack and resolve the dependencies - a dependency manager. There are some out there, but I haven't found anyone yet that is general, and not nested with a build tool.